# Is the feedback vertex set problem on planar bounded degree graphs hard?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, reference-request, graph-algorithms, np-hardness

Is it known whether the [feedback vertex set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feedback_vertex_set) problem on undirected planar graphs of bounded degree is $\mathsf{NP}$-hard?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to Garey and Johnson's book Vertex Cover is NP-complete on planar graphs of maximum degree four. Using a simple reduction from Vertex Cover to Feedback Vertex Set should give maximum degree eight and preserve planarity.

VC to FVS: Replace each edge by a triangle (or a double edge).

One note:
Garey and Johnson also state that directed FVS is NP-complete on planar digraphs with no in- or out-degree exceeding two. They do not specifically mention undirected FVS under such restrictions.

Answer (score 14):

**The answer is:** FVS is NP-complete on undirected planar graphs of maximum degree $4$; proved by Speckenmeyer, see [here](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/jgt.3190120311/abstract). By subdividing each edge by one new vertex, it easily follows that

> FVS is NP-complete even on undirected bipartite planar graphs of maximum 
>   degree $4$.

The degree constraint is best possibe, as FVS is polynomial for graphs of maximum degree at most three; see [here](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/12712/is-feedback-vertex-set-problem-is-solvable-in-polynomial-time-for-3-degree-bound?rq=1).

**Edit:** Ernst de Ridder's [graphclasses.org](http://graphclasses.org/classes/problem_Feedback_vertex_set.html) now contains all available information about FVS; including circa 550 polynomially solvable and circa 250 NP-c cases.

Comment: would you please explain more about the reduction, which is far from clear from me.  I don't have Speckenmeyer's thesis at hand (even I had, I won't be able to understand German). But I do have the paper you mentioned, which, however, only refers to his thesis.  On the other hand, I know that it's NP-hard on general graphs of maximum degree 4, as shown by Romeo Rizzi http://doi.org/10.1007/s00453-007-9112-8. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

According to Wikipedia Garey & Johnson also showed that " Vertex cover remains NP-complete ... even in planar graphs of degree at most 3."

Thus FVS is hard on planar graphs with maximum degree 6.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, in Speckenmeyer's PhD thesis, he demonstrates that the feedback vertex set problem is NP-hard for graphs of maximum degree 4. This claim appears [here](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/jgt.3190120311/abstract), for example.

For cubic graphs, the problem seems to be solvable in polynomial time. First, [Speckenmeyer](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/jgt.3190120311/abstract) demonstrates that for cubic graphs, the minimum-size feedback vertex set is equal to $n/2-z(G)+1$, where $n$ is the number of vertices and $z$ is the size of the largest nonseparating independent set. [Huang and Liu](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0012365X96002993) demonstrate that for cubic graphs, $z(G)$ is equal to the maximum genus of $G$, which can be calculated in polynomial time using the algorithm of [Furst, Gross, and McGeoch](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=44485).

Edit: didn't examine vb le's edit carefully enough...

Answer (score 1):

[image: gadgets]

Here are the two gadgets Speckenmeyer used in his Ph.D. thesis. We can start from planar graphs with maximum degree six, by a reduction from the vertex cover problem on cubic planar graphs. (Actually, we can start from a general planar graph and use similar gadgets to reduce its maximum degrees.)   We replace a vertex $x$ of degree six with the left gadget and a vertex $x$ of degree five with the right gadget. A solution $S$ to the original problem will be translated as follows:

if $x\in S$, then we take $\{u_2, u_4, v_3\}$; otherwise $\{v_1, v_5\}$.

Since the feedback vertex set problem can be solved in polynomial time in cubic graphs, even if they are not planar, the issue is settled. Source: http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0012-365X(88)90226-9

Comment: [This](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/269029032_Untersuchungen_zum_Feedback_Vertex_Set_Problem_in_ungerichteten_Graphen) is Speckenmeyer's Ph.D. thesis written in German.